# Customize log in view for Duende IdentityServer

Tags: identityserver4, duende-identity-server

I can't find the .cshtml file for customization the UI for the Duende Log In view.

I've even searched through the entire source for "Use a local account to log in" in order to find it, but it doesn't show up.

[image]

[image]

The index.cshtml under Account/Login is not the same view, and I can't find any LogIn view under Identity/Pages/Account.

How to customize the text for the login view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view is from ASP.Net Identity, and scaffolding the Login.cshtml resolved the issue.

Comment: When using IdentityServer it is recommended to use the template pages from the Duende Quickstart, they contain additional logic and validations that are not in the Asp.Net Identity templates. For external logins, the external scheme name used is different.